# What JavaScript chart library is used by SO to show reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How did you create your charts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3232/how-did-you-create-your-charts)

Do they use a public library? What is this?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3232/how-did-you-create-your-charts